# How to have two worlds in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a problem with leaflet when it come to have point near W180. The problem is the same as this one : https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/82

But on marine traffic we can see exactly what I try to achieve.

[image]

A continuous world where -180 W will cross this section so I can have a polyline which is not cut and rendered on the other side.

How is it possible since leaflet is able to have greater longitude than 180 ? I've been in the dark on this issue for some time.

I first tried to remove the `worldcopyjump` and the `maxbounds` but I don't know how to have two maps at the same time and how to avoid the polyline being cut.

[image]

---

### EDIT

I've been looking through the `mtMap` object on https://www.marinetraffic.com with one boat and there are using this settings :

```
center: [16.46769474828897, 216.73828125],
maxBounds: [[150,540],[-150,-540]],
```

My guess is that here are not using negative longitude, so maybe the solution is to have only positive longitude (greater than 180) ?

Comment: you should do what leaflet creator said in that link you posted. from what i see, if i am not mistaken, marinetraffic draws their map features using js (drawing on canvas or something), they are not leaflet objects.

Comment: Are you sure ? Because I've been looking to mtMap object in marine traffic and the maxBounds is `[150,540],[-150,-540]` So I think that they are using always positive longitude

Comment: no i am not 100% sure :/

Comment: I've made an edit. I think that in this context the solution may be to convert longitude so it can be greater than 180. Any idea how ?

Comment: try adding 360 to your longitudes like what leaflet creator said. also maybe this will help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18562/how-can-i-make-a-polyline-wrap-around-the-world

Comment: Well, well. It's working but now I have the same problem with the other markers since they have negative longitude too. This situation is a bit tricky. I will try your link, thanks